# Tkinter text split and output program

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a GUI program with Tkinter which would take in the text and then display all the sentences of the text one by one, moving on, when i click button 'Next'. Problem is that I have no experience with Tkinter, would anyone help me with this by posting some code?

Thanks

Comment: Posting code won't really help you... have you actually tried an attempt on your own? If not, why not?

Comment: However I suggest you post the code...

Comment: As @DylanLawrence commented, please try something and let us know what  didn't work (what error you get, etc.). We're not here to write code for you, but we'll gladly help you figure out a specific problem. You can always edit your own question to provide more details.